# Insert a row to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I have a dataframe:

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

   A  B  C
0  5  6  7
1  7  8  9

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

and I need to add a first row [2, 3, 4] to get:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
2  7  8  9
```

I've tried `append()` and `concat()` functions but can't find the right way how to do that.

How to add/insert series to dataframe?

Comment: note that it's better to use `s1.values` as opposed to `list(s1)` as you will be creating an entirely new list using `list(s1)`.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone loves pandas so much when something that should be so simple is such a pain in the ass and so slow.

Comment: @MattCochrane - Almost every time that I have found Pandas to be slow, I have found a different pandas method that is much faster later on or realised I was doing things weirdly backward. I find a lot of database functions like how you describe -I think that's due to the way database theory works, not down to Pandas specifically. I'm aware that there are other more specialised libraries that are faster for specific purposes, but few that do as much as broadly well as Pandas. If you / anyone has an alternate suggestion, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: @ciaranhaines I find pandas and numpy being just bandaids for the fact that python being a (very slow) interpreted language. There's only a handful of 'optimized' building blocks that they provide, versus the infinite scope of potential problems I regularly face. I spend countless time finding the right combination of those primitives that would do what I need, and more often than not I figure out that there isn't one. I can write an unvectorized loop to do the same in a fraction of my time, but it will run slow. Python is good only as a prototyping language.

Answer (score 261):

Just assign row to a particular index, using `loc`:

```
 df.loc[-1] = [2, 3, 4]  # adding a row
 df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
 df = df.sort_index()  # sorting by index
```

And you get, as desired:

```
    A  B  C
 0  2  3  4
 1  5  6  7
 2  7  8  9
```

See in Pandas documentation [Indexing: Setting with enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Comment: If you don't want to set with enlargement, but insert inside the dataframe, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888648/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-at-an-arbitrary-position-in-a-dataframe-using-pan?rq=1

Comment: shifting index alternative: df.sort().reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: df.sort is deprecated, use df.sort_index()

Comment: @Piotr - this works great, but what happens when you want to duplicate a row from your data frame, such as `df.loc[-1] = df.iloc[[0]]`, and insert that? The frame comes with an added index column giving error `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns`  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340571/adding-duplicate-row-to-dataframe-cannot-set-a-row-with-mismatched-columns)

Comment: I think `df.loc[-1] = [2, 3, 4]  # adding a row` is a bit misleading, as `-1` isn't the last row/element, as it is for Python arrays.

Comment: If you don't want to do any re-sorting of the index you can just do `df.loc[len(df)] = [2,3,4]`. Of course this makes assumption that the last index in the frame would be `len(df)-1`. However most of the dataframes I work with are structured like this.

Comment: @flow2k - while df.loc[-1] does not assign the new row to the end of the dataframe, it makes sure you are not overwriting anything.    In Greg 's example, you may accidentally overwrite data, if say, there is a filtering step without resetting the index.

Answer (score 78):

Testing a few answers it is clear that using `pd.concat()` is more efficient for large dataframes.

Comparing the performance using `dict` and `list`, the `list` is more efficient, but for small dataframes, using a `dict` should be no problem and somewhat more readable.

---

### 1st - `pd.concat() + list`

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
for i in range(10000):
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=df.columns), df], ignore_index=True)
```

**4.88 s** ± 47.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### 2nd - `pd.append() + dict` [removed as of [v2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes)]

```
%%timeit

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
for i in range(10000):
    df = df.append({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, ignore_index=True)
```

**10.2 s** ± 41.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### 3rd - `pd.DataFrame().loc + index operations`

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
for i in range(10000):
    df.loc[-1] = [1,2]
    df.index = df.index + 1
    df = df.sort_index()
```

**17.5 s** ± 37.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Note that `.append()` is deprecated [as of v1.4.0 (Jan 2022)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append)

Comment: If one really has no choice, `_append()` can be used instead of the removed `append()` (see some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449334/3002584)).

Answer (score 75):

Not sure how you were calling `concat()` but it should work as long as both objects are of the same type. Maybe the issue is that you need to cast your second vector to a dataframe? Using the df that you defined the following works for me:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4]], columns=['A','B','C'])
pd.concat([df2, df])
```

Comment: Best answer ^ :)

Comment: Should not be this modified a bit to do the job correctly? I think that code by @mgilbert inserts row at 0 but we end up with two rows having index 0. 

I think line two needs to be modified to look like the one below
pd.concat([df2, df]).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: One problem is if the row that we want to be inserted is `pd.Series` due to `iloc`. The solution is to use `iloc` with double bracket as shown in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181460/11671779).

Comment: @Thesmellofroses Or, better yet, `pd.concat([df2, df], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 32):

One way to achieve this is

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2, 3, 4]]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C']).append(df, ignore_index=True)
Out[330]: 
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
2  7  8  9
```

Generally, it's easiest to append dataframes, not series. In your case, since you want the new row to be "on top" (with starting id), and there is no function `pd.prepend()`, I first create the new dataframe and then append your old one.

`ignore_index` will ignore the old ongoing index in your dataframe and ensure that the first row actually starts with index `1` instead of restarting with index `0`.

*Typical Disclaimer: Cetero censeo ... appending rows is a quite inefficient operation. If you care about performance and can somehow ensure to first create a dataframe with the correct (longer) index and then just **inserting** the additional row into the dataframe, you should definitely do that. See:*

```
>>> index = np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=index)
>>> df2.loc[0:1] = [list(s1), list(s2)]
>>> df2
Out[336]: 
     A    B    C
0    5    6    7
1    7    8    9
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=index)
>>> df2.loc[1:] = [list(s1), list(s2)]
```

So far, we have what you had as `df`:

```
>>> df2
Out[339]: 
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    5    6    7
2    7    8    9
```

But now you can easily insert the row as follows. Since the space was preallocated, this is more efficient.

```
>>> df2.loc[0] = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> df2
Out[341]: 
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: That's nice workarround solution, I was trying to insert series into dataframe. It's good enough for me at the moment.

Comment: I like most the last option. This truly matches what I really want to do. Thank you @FooBar!

Answer (score 22):

I put together a short function that allows for a little more flexibility when inserting a row:

```
def insert_row(idx, df, df_insert):
    dfA = df.iloc[:idx, ]
    dfB = df.iloc[idx:, ]

    df = dfA.append(df_insert).append(dfB).reset_index(drop = True)

    return df
```

which could be further shortened to:

```
def insert_row(idx, df, df_insert):
    return df.iloc[:idx, ].append(df_insert).append(df.iloc[idx:, ]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Then you could use something like:

```
df = insert_row(2, df, df_new)
```

where `2` is the index position in `df` where you want to insert `df_new`.

Comment: Note that 2 is a *positional index* here, not *index* in ordinary pandas meaning.

Answer (score 15):

We can use [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html). This has the advantage of flexibility. You only need to specify the index you want to insert to.

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=[2, 3, 4], axis=0), columns=df.columns)

    0   1   2
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   7   8   9
```

For `np.insert(df.values, 0, values=[2, 3, 4], axis=0)`, 0 tells the function the place/index you want to place the new values.

Comment: Good solution for this example. Generally, you lose column names this way though

Comment: you can modify it slightly so you don't lose column names, I've edited the answer to show that

Answer (score 13):

It is pretty simple to add a row into a pandas `DataFrame`:

1. Create a regular Python dictionary with the same columns names as your `Dataframe`;
2. Use `pandas.append()` method and pass in the name of your dictionary, where `.append()` is a method on DataFrame instances;
3. Add `ignore_index=True` right after your dictionary name.

Comment: This is probably the most preferable option (circa 2020).

Comment: This function doesn't have an `inplace` argument, so: `df = df.append(your_dict, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: append has been deprecated for a while now

Answer (score 8):

this might seem overly simple but its incredible that a simple insert new row function isn't built in. i've read a lot about appending a new df to the original, but i'm wondering if this would be faster.

```
df.loc[0] = [row1data, blah...]
i = len(df) + 1
df.loc[i] = [row2data, blah...]
```

Comment: Did you mean "appending a new df" or just "appending a new row", as your code shows?

Comment: sorry my sentence wasn't clear. i've read other people solutions that concat/append a whole new dataframe with just a single row. but in my solution its just a single row in the existing dataframe no need for an additional dataframe to be created

Comment: OP wanted to *insert* a row at position 0. Your code *overwrites* whatever there is at position 0.

Answer (score 7):

Below would be the best way to insert a row into pandas dataframe without sorting and reseting an index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

def insert(df, row):
    insert_loc = df.index.max()

    if pd.isna(insert_loc):
        df.loc[0] = row
    else:
        df.loc[insert_loc + 1] = row

insert(df,[2,3,4])
insert(df,[8,9,0])
print(df)
```

Comment: why would you say this is the best way?

Comment: then it would be nice to provide evidence to support that claim, did you time it?

Comment: you can use pd.isna to avoid importing numpy

Answer (score 3):

`concat()` seems to be a bit faster than last row insertion and reindexing.
In case someone would wonder about the speed of two top approaches:

```
In [x]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])
     ...: for i in range(10000):
     ...:     df.loc[-1] = [1,2]
     ...:     df.index = df.index + 1
     ...:     df = df.sort_index()
```

17.1 s ± 705 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
In [y]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
     ...: for i in range(10000):
     ...:     df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=df.columns), df])
```

**6.53** s ± 127 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 2):

It just came up to me that maybe **T attribute** is a valid choice. **Transpose**, can get away from the somewhat misleading `df.loc[-1] = [2, 3, 4]` as @flow2k mentioned, and it is suitable for more universal situation such as you want to insert  `[2, 3, 4]` before arbitrary row, which is hard for `concat()`,`append()` to achieve. And there's no need to bare the trouble defining and debugging a function.

```
a = df.T
a.insert(0,'anyName',value=[2,3,4])
# just give insert() any column name you want, we'll rename it.
a.rename(columns=dict(zip(a.columns,[i for i in range(a.shape[1])])),inplace=True)
# set inplace to a Boolean as you need.
df=a.T
df

    A   B   C
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   7   8   9
```

I guess this can partly explain @MattCochrane 's complaint about why pandas doesn't have a method to insert a row like insert() does.

Answer (score 2):

For those that want to concat a row from the previous data frame, use double bracket (`[[...]]`) for `iloc`.

```py
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

#   A   B   C
# 0 5   6   7
# 1 7   8   9

pd.concat((df.iloc[[0]],  # [[...]] used to slice DataFrame as DataFrame
           df), ignore_index=True)

#   A   B   C
# 0 5   6   7
# 1 5   6   7
# 2 7   8   9
```

For duplicating or replicating arbitrary times, combine with star.

```py
pd.concat((df.iloc[[0]],
           df,
           *[df.iloc[[1]]] * 4), ignore_index=True)

#   A   B   C
# 0 5   6   7
# 1 7   8   9
# 2 7   8   9
# 3 7   8   9
# 4 7   8   9
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using a nested concat here?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins apparently, there is none. You can remove the concat inside and it just works. I might be use that due to copy paste from the previous section. Might edit and delete that after testing to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append the row to the end of the DataFrame, and then adjust the index.

For instance:

```py
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4]],columns=df.columns),ignore_index=True)
df.index = (df.index + 1) % len(df)
df = df.sort_index()
```

Or use `concat` as:

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6]],columns=df.columns),df],ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as following example:

`a_row = pd.Series([1, 2])`

`df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4], [5, 6]])`

`row_df = pd.DataFrame([a_row])`

`df = pd.concat([row_df, df], ignore_index=True)`

and the result is:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])
```

To insert a new row anywhere, you can specify the row position:
row_pos = -1 for inserting at the top
or row_pos = 0.5 for inserting between row 0 and row 1.

```
row_pos = -1
insert_row = [2,3,4]

df.loc[row_pos] = insert_row
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)

row_pos = -1

The outcome is:

    A   B   C
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   7   8   9

row_pos = 0.5

The outcome is:

    A   B   C
0   5   6   7
1   2   3   4
2   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Create empty df with columns name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
```

Insert new row:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [2, 3, 4]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [5, 6, 7]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the data structure of dataframe of pandas is a list of series (each series is a column), it is convenient to insert a column at any position.
So one idea I came up with is to first transpose your data frame, insert a column, and transpose it back. You may also need to rename the index (row names), like this:

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])
df = df.transpose()
df.insert(0, 2, [2,3,4])
df = df.transpose()
df.index = [i for i in range(3)]
df

    A   B   C
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   7   8   9
```

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way add a row in a pandas data frame is:

```py
DataFrame.loc[ location of insertion ]= list( )
```

Example :

```py
DF.loc[ 9 ] = [ ´Pepe’ , 33, ´Japan’ ]
```

NB: the length of your list should match that of the data frame.