# Is it possible to append Series to rows of DataFrame without making a list first?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataframe, series

I have some data I'm trying to organize into a `DataFrame` in `Pandas`.  I was trying to make each row a `Series` and append it to the `DataFrame`.  I found a way to do it by appending the `Series` to an empty `list` and then converting the `list` of `Series` to a `DataFrame`

e.g. `DF = DataFrame([series1,series2],columns=series1.index)`

This `list` to `DataFrame` step seems to be excessive.  I've checked out a few examples on here but none of the `Series` preserved the `Index` labels from the `Series` to use them as column labels.

My long way where columns are id_names and rows are type_names:
[image]

**Is it possible to append Series to rows of DataFrame without making a list first?**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

DF = DataFrame()
for sample,data in D_sample_data.items():
    SR_row = pd.Series(data.D_key_value)
    DF.append(SR_row)
DF.head()

TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name
```

Then I tried

```
DF = DataFrame()
for sample,data in D_sample_data.items():
    SR_row = pd.Series(data.D_key_value,name=sample)
    DF.append(SR_row)
DF.head()
```

Empty DataFrame

Tried [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)
Still getting an empty dataframe :/

**I am trying to get the Series to be the rows, where the index of the Series becomes the column labels of the DataFrame**

Comment: I'm trying to add rows. The index of the Series should be the columns of the DataFrame.  So rows would be samples and columns would be features.

Comment: Did you try adding a name to the Series, as the error message suggests?

Comment: You need to read the error message.  It tells you to add a name to the Series, or use `ignore_index=True`.  If you do either of those, it works fine.

Comment: There is no error message, it just gives me an empty dataframe

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Maybe an easier way would be to add the `pandas.Series` into the `pandas.DataFrame` with `ignore_index=True` argument to `DataFrame.append()`. Example -

```
DF = DataFrame()
for sample,data in D_sample_data.items():
    SR_row = pd.Series(data.D_key_value)
    DF = DF.append(SR_row,ignore_index=True)
```

Demo -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [5]: s = pd.Series([5,6],index=['A','B'])

In [6]: s
Out[6]:
A    5
B    6
dtype: int64

In [36]: df.append(s,ignore_index=True)
Out[36]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

---

Another issue in your code is that [`DataFrame.append()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is not in-place, it returns the appended dataframe, you would need to assign it back to your original dataframe for it to work. Example -

```
DF = DF.append(SR_row,ignore_index=True)
```

---

To preserve the labels, you can use your solution to include name for the series along with assigning the appended DataFrame back to `DF`. Example -

```
DF = DataFrame()
for sample,data in D_sample_data.items():
    SR_row = pd.Series(data.D_key_value,name=sample)
    DF = DF.append(SR_row)
DF.head()
```

Comment: I saw that on "Insert a row to pandas dataframe" link above.  I'm trying to mess around with it. Maybe there is something that I'm not doing correctly.

Comment: Ah man, thanks! I didn't catch the DF = DF.append() That's way different than list appending.  Sorry I missed that.

Comment: I lost the Index labels. Is there any way to preserve this?

Comment: you can use your `name` solution with `DF = DF.append(SR_row)` . Updated the answer with that example.

Comment: **Warning**: df.append is now deprecated and you should try using pd.concat insted

Comment: This is no longer valid due to append being deprecated. Please update to concat. 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?

Answer (score 31):

[`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) does not modify the DataFrame in place.  You need to do `df = df.append(...)` if you want to reassign it back to the original variable.

Comment: This is a deviation from python normal behavior and is worthwhile to always keep in mind.

Comment: Using `df.append` is deprecated since [pandas 1.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append) and should be replaced by [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 17):

append is deprecating so, the best choice would be to_frame().T

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','mark'],'job':['manager','salesman'],'age':[43,23]})
ser1 = df1.iloc[-1]
pd.concat([df1,ser1.to_frame().T],ignore_index=True)

   name       job age
0  john   manager  43
1  mark  salesman  23
2  mark  salesman  23
```

Answer (score 13):

Something like this could work...

```
mydf.loc['newindex'] = myseries
```

Here is an example where I used it...

```
stats = df[['bp_prob', 'ICD9_prob', 'meds_prob', 'regex_prob']].describe()

stats
Out[32]: 
          bp_prob   ICD9_prob   meds_prob  regex_prob
count  171.000000  171.000000  171.000000  171.000000
mean     0.179946    0.059071    0.067020    0.126812
std      0.271546    0.142681    0.152560    0.207014
min      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25%      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
50%      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.013116
75%      0.309019    0.065248    0.066667    0.192954
max      1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000

medians = df[['bp_prob', 'ICD9_prob', 'meds_prob', 'regex_prob']].median()

stats.loc['median'] = medians

stats
Out[36]: 
           bp_prob   ICD9_prob   meds_prob  regex_prob
count   171.000000  171.000000  171.000000  171.000000
mean      0.179946    0.059071    0.067020    0.126812
std       0.271546    0.142681    0.152560    0.207014
min       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25%       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
50%       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.013116
75%       0.309019    0.065248    0.066667    0.192954
max       1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
median    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.013116
```

Answer (score 11):

Convert the series to a dataframe and transpose it, then append normally.

```
srs = srs.to_frame().T
df = df.append(srs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this command. See the example given below:

[image: Before image]

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Product 9',99,9.99,8.88,1.11]

df
```

[image: After Image]

Answer (score 1):

This would work as well:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
new_line = pd.Series({'A2M': 4.059, 'A2ML1': 4.28}, name='HCC1419')
df = df.append(new_line, ignore_index=False)
```

The `name` in the Series will be the index in the dataframe. `ignore_index=False` is the important flag in this case.