# empty dataframes when appending series with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, append, series

I need to append many series to a dataframe (averages_per_trip) but am getting empty dataframes each time. It doesn't even work once. What gives? (reference [Is it possible to append Series to rows of DataFrame without making a list first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094056/is-it-possible-to-append-series-to-rows-of-dataframe-without-making-a-list-first))

Comment: What is `averages` used in your code above? Another dataframe?

Comment: What you have in intput is not clear. Could you give us the head of all your input df so we can reproduce your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the append function.  It does not update the initial dataframe, you must:

```
df = df.append(stuff)
```