# add a row at top in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon','sam','jane','bob'],
           'age': [30,25,18,26],
           'sex':['male','male','female','male']})


   age  name     sex
0   30   jon    male
1   25   sam    male
2   18  jane  female
3   26   bob    male
```

I want to insert a new row at the first position

name: dean, age: 45, sex: male

```
   age  name     sex
0   45  dean    male
1   30   jon    male
2   25   sam    male
3   18  jane  female
4   26   bob    male
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Comment: @MaxU i edited my question

Comment: One more question - is it going to be a regular (frequent) operation  or not?

Comment: @MaxU yes it would be a frequent operation

Comment: Incase someone looking for making columns as first row, 
 df.T.reset_index().T

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If it's going to be a frequent operation, then it makes sense (in terms of performance) to gather the data into a list first and then use `pd.concat([], ignore_index=True)` (similar to [@Serenity's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408750/5741205)):

Demo:

```
data = []

# always inserting new rows at the first position - last row will be always on top    
data.insert(0, {'name': 'dean', 'age': 45, 'sex': 'male'})
data.insert(0, {'name': 'joe', 'age': 33, 'sex': 'male'})
#...

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), df], ignore_index=True)

In [56]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), df], ignore_index=True)
Out[56]:
   age  name     sex
0   33   joe    male
1   45  dean    male
2   30   jon    male
3   25   sam    male
4   18  jane  female
5   26   bob    male
```

PS I wouldn't call `.append()`, `pd.concat()`, `.sort_index()` too frequently (for each single row) as it's pretty expensive. So the idea is to do it in chunks...

Answer (score 69):

Probably this is not the most efficient way but:

```
df.loc[-1] = ['45', 'Dean', 'male']  # adding a row
df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
 age  name     sex
0  45  Dean    male
1  30   jon    male
2  25   sam    male
3  18  jane  female
4  26   bob    male
```

Comment: `df.index + 1` - nice idea!

Comment: I would just add slightly cleaner last line: df.sort_index(inplace=True)

Comment: You plagiarised this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24284680/4909087

Comment: @coldspeed: look at dates of creation please

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This was posted 3 years later. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Call Centre Executive, It was not my intention, mostly likely I saw the answer before, used it for my own code and then answered here when a similar question popped up.

Comment: Well that would be double plagiarism then.

Comment: The answer could be deleted or whatever... I thought I was plagarising my own solution

Comment: What are we here for if not for sharing solutions.

Answer (score 7):

[@edyvedy13's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408736/5125275) worked great for me. However it needs to be updated for the [deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408736/5125275) of pandas' `sort` method - now replaced with `sort_index`.

```
 df.loc[-1] = ['45', 'Dean', 'male']  # adding a row
 df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
 df = df.sort_index()  # sorting by index
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [pandas.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and reindex new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon','sam','jane','bob'],
           'age': [30,25,18,26],
           'sex':['male','male','female','male']})
# new line
line = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'dean', 'age': 45, 'sex': 'male'}, index=[0])
# concatenate two dataframe
df2 = pd.concat([line,df.ix[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
```

Output:

```
   age  name     sex
0   45  dean    male
1   30   jon    male
2   25   sam    male
3   18  jane  female
4   26   bob    male
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon','sam','jane','bob'],
           'age': [30,25,18,26],
           'sex': ['male','male','female','male']})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['dean'], 'age': [45], 'sex':['male']})
df1 = df1.append(df)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

That works

Answer (score 1):

This will work for me.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jon','sam','jane','bob'],
...            'age': [30,25,18,26],
...            'sex':['male','male','female','male']})     >>> df
   age  name     sex
0   30   jon    male
1   25   sam    male
2   18  jane  female
3   26   bob    male
>>> df.loc['a']=[45,'dean','male']
>>> df
   age  name     sex
0   30   jon    male
1   25   sam    male
2   18  jane  female
3   26   bob    male
a   45  dean    male
>>> newIndex=['a']+[ind for ind in df.index if ind!='a']
>>> df=df.reindex(index=newIndex)
>>> df
   age  name     sex
a   45  dean    male
0   30   jon    male
1   25   sam    male
2   18  jane  female
3   26   bob    male
```