# How to insert a row to dataframe fast?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert data to the first row of a dataframe and remove the last row from the dataframe. I need to do this operation a lot of times.

From these two questions. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408621/add-a-row-at-top-in-pandas-dataframe)[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)
I have some code like this:

```
targetDF = pd.concat([sourceDF[sourceDF.index == targetDate], targetDF[:]])
targetDF.drop(targetDF.tail(1).index, inplace = True)
```

This will do from:

```
                Volume     Today      Lag1      Lag2      Lag3      Lag4      Lag5  Direction
2000-05-22  23956801.0  0.338821  1.724165 -0.343514  3.191463  0.714161  0.000000        1.0
2000-05-19  50544773.0 -1.013452  0.338821  1.724165 -0.343514  3.191463  0.714161       -1.0
...                ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...
2000-01-04   3194413.0  7.397314  5.187307 -1.977310 -0.840434 -2.458993  1.666694        1.0

[100 rows x 8 columns]
```

To:

```
                Volume     Today      Lag1      Lag2      Lag3      Lag4      Lag5  Direction
2000-05-23  21822575.0  1.724165 -0.343514  3.191463  0.714161  0.000000 -1.754358        1.0
2000-05-22  23956801.0  0.338821  1.724165 -0.343514  3.191463  0.714161  0.000000        1.0
...                ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...
2000-01-05   6058531.0  5.187307 -1.977310 -0.840434 -2.458993  1.666694  1.408448        1.0

[100 rows x 8 columns]
```

From the answer of Question 1, `pd.concat()` is expansive. So I would like to ask if there is a better way to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: <Unrelated> Looks like your lags are going the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pandas.concat`

Modification of what you were doing

```
targetDF = pd.concat([sourceDF.loc[[targetDate]], targetDF.iloc[:-1]])
```

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.append`

Or use a `DataFrame` method

```
targetDF = sourceDF.loc[[targetDate]].append(targetDF.iloc[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in *Pandas* the physical order of rows is not so important
and may be changed using either *sort_index* or *sort_values*.

Note also that each row is identified by an **index** and just like in
a database, it should be **unique** within the current DataFrame.

So my concept is:

- If you want to **add** a new row, add it with index value **one bigger**
  than the max index so far, using *append* (at the end).
- If you want to **delete** a row, delete the row with the **lowest** value
  of the index (from the beginning).

So the order of rows is **opposite** to your wish, but you still are able
to process them in "your" order (from the just inserted row to the
"oldest" row.

Just access rows in **reverse order** than the index. Something like:

```
df.loc[::-1]
```