# add row to dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a median row to the top. Based on this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408888/5986651) I do the following:

`pd.concat([df.median(),df],axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

**Shape of DF:** `50000 x 226`
**Shape expected:** `50001 x 226`
**Shape of modified DF:** `500213 x 227` ???

What am I doing wrong? I am unable to understand what is going on?

Comment: Can you give us a sample dataframe with more entries and expected output. May use this link as guide to give a clearer question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you wanted is like this:

```py
dfn = pd.concat([df.median().to_frame().T, df], ignore_index=True)
```

create some sample data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5), columns= list('ABCDE'))
dfn = pd.concat([df.median().to_frame().T, df])

df
    A   B   C   D   E
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2   10  11  12  13  14
3   15  16  17  18  19


df.median().to_frame().T
     A    B    C     D     E
0  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5  11.5


dfn
      A     B     C     D     E
0   7.5   8.5   9.5  10.5  11.5
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
2  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
3  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0
```

`df.median()` is an Series, with row index of `A, B, C, D, E`, so when you concat `df.median()` with `df`, the result is that:

```py
pd.concat([df.median(),df], axis=0)

      0     A     B     C     D     E
A   7.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
B   8.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
C   9.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
D  10.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
E  11.5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
0   NaN   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1   NaN   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
2   NaN  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
3   NaN  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0
```

Comment: Thanks :) I tried `pd.DataFrame(df.median())` but that didn't work as well. I guess because of the missing transpose!

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([df.median(),df],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

this code creates a row for you but that is not a DataFrame it is a Series. So you want to convert the series to DataFrame
so you can use

```
.to_frame().T
```

to your code then your code become

```
pd.concat([df.median().to_frame().T,df],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```