# How to combine two dataframes of unequal lenght on a key as connector?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which are uneven in the number of rows. Now I want to add them horizontally by aligning the second dataframe based on a key ("flag"). However, the flag serves merely as a connector at a specific row to the first (base) df which means the second dataframe should be pasted at that connector point. Please see visual for what I mean in case it is not clear.

I tried looking into `merge, concat, join etc` but it will join it does not seem quiet like what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: @user2552108 you basically need to connect the two dataframe on where the rows are yellow which will result on the output Final

Comment: What if you have multiple 1's in each dataframe how will second dataframe be placed in that case?

Comment: @Muhammadhassan there will NEVER be multiple 1's! Only one-time this can occur.

Comment: @titu84hh Please accept my answer below if it answers your question.  Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408621/add-a-row-at-top-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df_base = pd.DataFrame(data={'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                             'transaction_value':[1,1,2,2,5,6,9]})
df_group2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'flag':[0,0,1,0,0],
                               'transaction_value':[1,1,2,2,5]})

diff = df_base['flag'].argmax() - df_group2['flag'].argmax()
df_group2.index = df_group2.index + diff
print(df_base.join(df_group2[['transaction_value']], rsuffix='_group2'))
```

Output:

```
   flag  transaction_value  transaction_value_group2
0     0                  1                       NaN
1     0                  1                       NaN
2     0                  2                       1.0
3     0                  2                       1.0
4     1                  5                       2.0
5     0                  6                       2.0
6     0                  9                       5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dif = df1['flag'].idxmax() - df2['flag'].idxmax()
df2.index = df2.index + dif
df1.merge(df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

[image]

Can make use of the above idea.  Need to clean up the column names and drop the extra column.  Works if dif is -ve.

Drop 1st 3 rows of df1

[image]

Comment: thanks but the output in excel you show has nans for x when it should be for y. can you double check please?

Comment: The image is updated .