# How Can I insert a list into a specific column in a data frame by specifying the column index in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe (my_data) like this:

```
 ID  col1  col2  col3
 100  nan   nan   nan
 101  nan   nan   nan
 102  nan   nan   nan
 103  nan   nan   nan
```

and I have a list "My_list" with one column and n rows:

```
[val1
val2
val3
val4]
```

I want to insert the list with 1 column and n rows into the dataframe in a specific column in a loop. I can not use the name of
the column because in a loop the name of the headers will be changed. The output should be like this:

```
 ID  col1  col2  col3
 100  nan  val1   nan
 101  nan  val2   nan
 102  nan  val3   nan
 103  nan  val4   nan
```

So I need to use index or something like this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check this out something similar but with rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `df.iloc`! It allowes you to slice the dataframe by index. To replace the values in a column with index `i` with the values in the list `lst`:

```
df.iloc[:,i] = lst
```