# How to keep column titles when inserting a sum row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
       Name    y1    y2   y3                  
 1     Ben     01    02   03
 2     Jane    04    05   06
 3     Sarah   07    07   06
```

I am trying to add in a row in my dataframe which provides a total of the rows in each column. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=[df.sum(axis=0)], axis=0))
df.set_value(0, 0,'total')
df.head()
```

This is successful, but also removes my column names like this:

```
       0       1     2    3                     
 0     Total   12    14   15
 1     Ben     01    02   03
 2     Jane    04    05   06
 3     Sarah   07    07   06
```

rather than returning this as desired:

```
       Name    y1    y2   y3                      
 0     Total   12    14   15
 1     Ben     01    02   03
 2     Jane    04    05   06
 3     Sarah   07    07   06
```

I have tried inserting

```
Index(['Name'], name=df.index.name)
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=[df.sum(axis=0)], Index(['Name'], name=df.index.name) axis=0))
```

but this just returns the error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe/24287210

Comment: Dream of each OP - a lot of perfect answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `np.insert` should be very fast, but is necessary create `index` with non numeric columns first:

```
#create index from `Name` column
df = df.set_index('Name')

#add first value to index
idx = np.insert(df.index, 0, 'Total')
#add columns and index parameters to DataFrame contructor and last reset index
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, df.sum(), axis=0), 
                  columns=df.columns, 
                  index=idx).reset_index()
print (df)
    Name  y1  y2  y3
0  Total  12  14  15
1    Ben   1   2   3
2   Jane   4   5   6
3  Sarah   7   7   6
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on a much bigger data set too. I also substituted in .mean for .sum which may be useful to others looking to do similar.    idx = np.insert(df.index, 0, 'Mean')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, df.mean(), axis=0),

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid this is to add a new row via `.loc`, then move it to the top:

```
df.loc[len(df)+1] = ['Total'] + df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=0).tolist()

df = df.loc[[df.index[-1]] + df.index[:-1].tolist(), :]

#     Name  y1  y2  y3
# 4  Total  12  14  15
# 1    Ben   1   2   3
# 2   Jane   4   5   6
# 3  Sarah   7   7   6
```

You can use `df.reset_index` afterwards if this is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it this way, using `select_types`, `assign`, and `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
             .sum()
             .to_frame()
             .T
             .assign(Name='Total'),df])
```

Output:

```
    Name  y1  y2  y3
0  Total  12  14  15
1    Ben   1   2   3
2   Jane   4   5   6
3  Sarah   7   7   6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.concat` to stack two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = ...

df_total = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(), columns=["Total"]).T.reset_index()
df_total.columns = df.columns
df = pd.concat([df_total, df])
#     Name  y1  y2  y3
# 0  Total  12  14  15
# 1    Ben   1   2   3
# 2   Jane   4   5   6
# 3  Sarah   7   7   6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
s=df.sum()    
s.loc['Name']='Total'
df.loc[0]=s    
df.sort_index()
Out[457]: 
    Name  y1  y2  y3
0  Total  12  14  15
1    Ben   1   2   3
2   Jane   4   5   6
3  Sarah   7   7   6
```