# How to have the first row of a dataframe to be left empty (value_counts function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe built using (value_counts) function. When I call that dataframe in the body of the email it gets displayed as below

Updated view of the dataframe:

```
  Exact match   169
1 Missing       121
2 Dropped by 1% 1
```

I would like to have the header (or the first row) to be empty or have a title but have the first row pushed to the second row in the dataframe. Given below is the syntax:

```
SumMail = pd.value_counts(Output1['Status'].values)
```

Given below is the view of `Output1` dataframe:

```
      Status
0 ABC Exact match
1 DEF Dropped by 1%
2 XYZ Exact match
```

Could anyone advice.

Comment: Please post your dataframe as text, not as an image.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.values`? Its hard to tell how to solve it without knowing what is `Output1`

Comment: I would suggest trying inserting a row of `[np.nan, np.nan]` at the 0th position (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

The function `pd.value_counts` takes a Series as input. Therefore, using a `.values` removes the column name info and converts it to an array, which is why it uses the 1st row as column name afterwards. Removing the `.values` will solve that.

### Example

```
Output1 = pd.DataFrame({'':['a','b','c','d','e'],'Status':['Exact match','Dropped by 1%','Exact match','Missing','Exact match']})
print(Output1)
#              Status
# 0  a    Exact match
# 1  b  Dropped by 1%
# 2  c    Exact match
# 3  d        Missing
# 4  e    Exact match

# First option
print(pd.value_counts(Output1['Status']))
# Exact match      3
# Missing          1
# Dropped by 1%    1
# Name: Status, dtype: int64 # Note the Name still present

# Second option
print(pd.DataFrame(pd.value_counts(Output1['Status'])))
#                    Status
# Exact match         3
# Missing             1
# Dropped by 1%       1
```

Comment: Hey xg.plt.py, I did remove ".values" from the code but the output returned was in the same format...

Comment: How are you printing `SumMail`?

Comment: Thanks xg, I am able to have a header column and the results are shown from row 2 onwards. However, how can I rename the labels in the header columns. 

Given below is the view of my dataframe

    ,Unnamed:0,Status
    0,Missing,3
    1,Exact match,1
    2,NaN,1

I have tried using rename function but still no luck, could you please help. Thanks..

Comment: @Taukheer Have you tried what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas)? If it does not work for you then it's probably worth another quesion for this.