# How to insert rows into dataframes in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm very new to pandas and dataframes.

I have two lists in python which contains columns and values that needs to be inserted for that columns in a row.

For Ex:

```
col_list = ['column1', 'column3', 'column4', 'column6', ...]
val_list = ['value1', 'value3', 'value4', 'value6', ...]
```

How can I insert these values from val_list in columns in col_list for a specific row.

And I need to iterate multiple times.

These value and column list will change for every iteration but the order of *column1 - value1, column2 - value2* doesn't change.

If the ith element in col_list is **col-i**, then ith element in val_list will be **val-i**.

How can I enter data in only specific columns that are in col_list into pandas dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Note: You can't insert only data into certain columns in a new row, the rest of the row will be `NaN`. If you want to update an existing row, then you can use `loc` and `iloc` indexing to get to where you want

Comment: The remaining column values can be `Nan`. No problem with that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As in the link above,  [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Here is a great resource for future uses: http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html

Answer (score 0):

```
my_pd = pd.DataFrame(np.array(val_list)).T
my_pd.columns = col_list
pd.concat([a, my_pd], ignore_index=True)
```

I don't really see this in other answers, but here is a way to use `concat` to join your list to the end of the pandas `dataframe`. It's tricky though, usually it's best to iterate through all the list you want to join, create a new `DataFrame` off that and then joining those 2 `df` together, it will be much easier and faster.