# Search for a word and insert an empty row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and developing a code

I want to search for a word in a column and if a match is found, i want to insert an empty row below that.

My code is below

```
If df.columnname=='total':
  Df.insert
```

Could someone pls help me.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output .Thanks

Comment: Use `loc` or `concat`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe/24287210

Comment: Please indent your code properly and provide [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
from numpy import nan as Nan
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['A0', 'total', 'total', 'A3'],'Column2': ['B0', 'B1', 
'B2', 'B3'],'Column3': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],'Column4': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 
'D3']},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

count = 0
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["Column1"] == 'total':
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df1.values, index+1+count, values=[" "] 
             * len(df1.columns), axis=0),columns = df1.columns)
        count += 1
print (df1)
```

Input:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0      A0      B0      C0      D0
1   total      B1      C1      D1
2   total      B2      C2      D2
3      A3      B3      C3      D3
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0      A0      B0      C0      D0
1   total      B1      C1      D1
2                                
3   total      B2      C2      D2
4                                
5      A3      B3      C3      D3
```

Comment: That really worked and thank you..... But if we are finding the same word again while iterating, then next time the row is inserted above.

Comment: @nikhilthms94 I have updated my code, Now it working correct.I used `count` variable to avoid issue.

Comment: Now its perfect. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

Do give the following a try:

```
>>>df

         id     Label
0         1       A
1         2       B
2         3       B
3         4       B
4         5       A
5         6       B
6         7       A
7         8       A
8         9       C
9        10       C
10       11       C

# Create a separate dataframe with the id of the rows to be duplicated
df1 = df.loc[df['Label']=='B', 'id']
# Join it back and reset the index
df = pd.concat(df,df1).sort_index()

>>>df
             id     Label
    0         1       A
    1         2       B
    2         2       NaN
    3         3       B
    4         3       NaN
    5         4       B
    6         4       NaN
    7         5       A
    8         6       B
    9         6       NaN
   10         7       A
   11         8       A
   12         9       C
   13        10       C
   14        11       C
```

Comment: yes and you may want to set the entire row as nan so check the duplicates on other columns except labels and set to nan. :) +1

Comment: @Kerwei Your code do not added any empty row at particular position, It just concat two DF and sort based on index.Read Question carefully what exact he want. He wanted to insert empty row at specific position in DF.

Comment: I believe you can achieve the same effects as your output by adding the following 2 optional lines 1. ```df['id'] = df.index``` 2. ```df.set_index('id')```