# How to add values to a row if a column exist in a df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of items that I loop to find values example: dfexample1

```
#List of documents:   
list1 = ['doc1.pdf', 'doc2.pdf', 'doc3.pdf']

#each document contains a DF with the same Test columns with the same Tets letters:
```

doc1.pdf: df1

```
 Test | Value
  a   |  5.5
  b   |  6.5
  c   |  8.5
```

doc2.pdf: df2

```
 Test | Value
  a   |  6.5
  b   |  11.5
  c   |  13.5
```

doc3.pdf: df3

```
 Test | Value
  a   |  12.5
  b   |  3.5
  c   |  9.5
```

I have a df with the Test values being the columns

```
a | b | c
```

in each loop I am trying to extract the value of each test and ad them to the df.

in the first example the same analysis will be repeated over a list of pdf documents so I need to extract each of those values and add them into de df.

I tried this:

```
for items in list:
    for index, row in dfexample1.iterrows():
        if item in row[0]:
           value1=row[1]
```

Verifying if value exists as column in the df:

```
 if items in df.columns:
    #How can I insert this value in the next row?
```

My expected result would be:

```
  a | b  | c
 5.5|6.5 |8.5
 6.5|11.5|13.5
12.5| 3.5|9.5
```

.T would not work I guess because the dfexample1 will be repeated with different values while looping across documents.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @ScottBoston I just update the post, so eventually if I have 10 documents the df would need to have 10 rows with a value for each column.

Comment: Can you create a more robust test case?  Maybe with muliple rows and expected output?

Comment: `pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['a', 'b', 'c'], axis='index') # maybe axis='columns'?`