# copy columns name into first row of data in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7

I have a pandas dataframe like following when I write this dataframe into google sheets I found out header is missing. My questions is how to make it work? or copy columns name into first row of data and other data does not change?

```
import pandas as pd

year = [2005, 2006, 2007]
A = [4, 5, 7]
B = [3, 3, 9]
C = [1, 7, 6]
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'year' : year, 'A' : A, 'B' : B, 'C' : C}, columns=['year', 'A', 'B', 'c'])

Out[25]: 
   A  B  C  year
0  4  3  1  2005
1  5  3  7  2006
2  7  9  6  2007

#want output
Out[25]: 
   A  B  C  year
0  A  B  C  year
1  4  3  1  2005
2  5  3  7  2006
3  7  9  6  2007
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24284680/11127365

For your case, the first line will be df_old.loc[-1] = df_old.columns

Comment: When the suggested answer works, please vote it so that other people will know that it works.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df_old.columns.values[None,:],columns=df_old.columns).\
       append(df_old).\
       reset_index(drop=True)
df
   year  A  B    c
0  year  A  B    c
1  2005  4  3  NaN
2  2006  5  3  NaN
3  2007  7  9  NaN
```