# Split a string in pandas row and insert new rows by enlarging the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

|  | no | word | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | one | to_check |
| 1 | 1 | two | to_check |
| 2 | 2 | :) | emoticon |
| 3 | 3 | dr. | to_check |
| 4 | 4 | "future" | to_check |
| 5 | 5 | to | to_check |
| 6 | 6 | be | to_check |

I want to iterate trough each row to find quotes at word initial and final positions and create a DataFrame like this:

|  | no | word | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | one | to_check |
| 1 | 1 | two | to_check |
| 2 | 2 | :) | emoticon |
| 3 | 3 | dr. | to_check |
| 4 | 4 | " | quotes |
| 5 | 4 | future | word |
| 6 | 4 | " | quotes |
| 7 | 5 | to | to_check |
| 8 | 6 | be | to_check |

I can strip quotes and split the word into three pieces but I got the this DataFrame, it overwrites the last two rows:

|  | no | word | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | one | to_check |
| 1 | 1 | two | to_check |
| 2 | 2 | :) | emoticon |
| 3 | 3 | dr. | to_check |
| 4 | 4 | " | quotes |
| 5 | 4 | future | word |
| 6 | 4 | " | quotes |

I tried df.loc[index], df.iloc[index], df.at[index] but none of them helped me to extend the number of rows in the DataFrame.

Is it possible to add new rows at specific index without overwriting last two rows?

Comment: Did you try any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe ?

Comment: what code are you currently using?

Answer (score 6):

In your case you can `split` then `explode`

```
out = df.assign(word = df.word.str.split(r'(\")')).explode('word').\
           loc[lambda x : x['word']!='']
   no    word    status
0   0     one  to_check
1   1     two  to_check
2   2      :)  emoticon
3   3     dr.  to_check
4   4       "  to_check
4   4  future  to_check
4   4       "  to_check
5   5      to  to_check
6   6      be  to_check
```

For change the status

```
out['status'] = np.where(out['word'].eq('"'), 'quotes',out['status'])
```

Comment: This is beautiful! You must change `status` as well though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient however I think it is very readable, maybe you could use it if you don't care too much of efficiency.

```
no_lst = list()
word_lst = list()
status_lst = list()

def check_quote(w):
    if w.startswith('"') and w.endswith('"'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    word = getattr(row, "word")
    status = getattr(row, "status")
    
    if check_quote(word):
        no_lst += [i,i,i]
        stripped_w = word.strip('"')
        
        word_lst.append('"')
        word_lst.append(stripped_w)
        word_lst.append('"')
        
        status_lst += ["quotes", "word", "quotes"]
        continue
        
    no_lst.append(i)
    word_lst.append(word)
    status_lst.append(status)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"no":no_lst,
                   "word":word_lst,
                   "status":status_lst})
```

Answer (score 0):

you try creating this function.

```
def InsertRow(df, idx):
    df1 = df[0:idx]
    df2 = df[idx:]

    arr_empty = np.array([idx-1, '\"', 'quotes'])

    df1.iloc[-1]=arr_empty
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

    return df
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).