# adding consequently items of a list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, dataset

As a practice, I have created the following dataset of reading books:

```
data = [("Il nome della rosa","Umberto Eco", 1980), 
        ("L'amore che ti meriti","Daria Bignardi", 2014), 
        ("Memorie dal sottsuolo", " Fëdor Dostoevskij", 1864), 
        ("Oblomov", "Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov ", 1859)]

index = range(1,5,1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Books'Title", "Authors", "Publishing Year"], index = index)
df
```

Then I added a fourth column as follows

```
pubhouses = ["Bompiani", "Mondadori", "Rizzoli", "Feltrinelli"]
df.insert(3, 'Publication Houses', pubhouses)
df
```

And now I would like to add as follows (I mean as rows 5 and 6) the following item, always by using the list

```
l_row = [("Le avventure di Pinocchio", "Carlo Collodi", 1883, "Giunti"), 
         ('Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed altri amori malinconici', "Daria Bignardi", 2022, "Mondadori")]
```

I have tried adding other titles

```
l_row = [("Le avventure di Pinocchio", "Carlo Collodi", 1883, "Giunti"), 
         ('Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed altri amori malinconici', "Daria Bignardi", 2022, "Mondadori")]
```

the following code which does not work:

```
df.loc[5::6] = l_row
df
```

Since I am at the very beginning I would be very willing to explore different solutions to explore how to add as follows the further list's names (I thought also about a for loop which I do not how to set out)

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to do is an anti-pattern. A better cleaner way (and where you can validate the incoming rows). Create a dataframe from the new rows, and then concat with the previous dataframe - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code. It uses **numpy.vstack** to add **list rows** to existing data frame. Using your code from above for continuity, new code starts after the commented line ***Adding list rows to dataframe***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [("Il nome della rosa","Umberto Eco", 1980), 
        ("L'amore che ti meriti","Daria Bignardi", 2014), 
        ("Memorie dal sottsuolo", " Fëdor Dostoevskij", 1864), 
        ("Oblomov", "Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov ", 1859)]

index = range(1,5,1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Books'Title", "Authors", "Publishing Year"], index = index)

pubhouses = ["Bompiani", "Mondadori", "Rizzoli", "Feltrinelli"]
df.insert(3, 'Publication Houses', pubhouses)

### Adding list rows to dataframe

l_row = [("Le avventure di Pinocchio", "Carlo Collodi", 1883, "Giunti"), 
         ('Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed altri amori malinconici', "Daria Bignardi", 2022, "Mondadori")]


pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.values,  np.vstack(l_row)]), columns =  df.columns)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. If you would like to suggest a way to perform the same through a for loop or another iteration method, feel free to extend your answer.