# How to make possible to add new row to a dataset without changing index

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, row

I have the following dataset

```
       Books'Title                        Authors  Publishing Year  \
1     Il nome della rosa                    Umberto Eco             1980   
2  L'amore che ti meriti                 Daria Bignardi             2014   
3  Memorie dal sottsuolo              Fëdor Dostoevskij             1864   
4                Oblomov  Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov              1859   

  Publication House  
1          Bompiani  
2         Mondadori  
3           Rizzoli  
4       Feltrinelli
```

I have built it as follows:

```
data = [("Il nome della rosa","Umberto Eco", 1980), 
        ("L'amore che ti meriti","Daria Bignardi", 2014), 
        ("Memorie dal sottsuolo", " Fëdor Dostoevskij", 1864), 
        ("Oblomov", "Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov ", 1859)]

index = range(1,5,1)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Books'Title", "Authors", "Publishing Year"], index = index)
data

pubhouses = ["Bompiani", "Mondadori", "Rizzoli", "Feltrinelli"]
data.insert(3, 'Publication House', pubhouses)
data
```

I am trying adding new rows as follows in the 4th position but without changing the original index of the dataset. By following the suggestions of this website page [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)

```
new_row = ['Le avventure di Pinocchio', 'Carlo Collodi',  1883, 'Giunti']
new_row 

for i in range(1, 6):
    data.loc[-1] = new_row
    data.index = data.index + 1
    data = data.sort_index()
data
```

But I am getting the following dataset

[image]

May I ask - since I am a beginner how to possibly perform this operation? How would it be possible to exchange the original index of the dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your index is numeric and `loc` and `iloc` are the same here (and only here), you can enlarge your dataframe easily:

```
data.loc[data.index[-1] + 1] = new_row
print(data)

# Output
                 Books'Title                        Authors  Publishing Year Publication House
1         Il nome della rosa                    Umberto Eco             1980          Bompiani
2      L'amore che ti meriti                 Daria Bignardi             2014         Mondadori
3      Memorie dal sottsuolo              Fëdor Dostoevskij             1864           Rizzoli
4                    Oblomov  Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov              1859       Feltrinelli
5  Le avventure di Pinocchio                  Carlo Collodi             1883            Giunti
```

Else you have to build a dataframe and concatenate it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([new_row], columns=data.columns)
data = pd.concat([data, df], ignore_index=True)
print(data)

# Output
                 Books'Title                        Authors  Publishing Year Publication House
0         Il nome della rosa                    Umberto Eco             1980          Bompiani
1      L'amore che ti meriti                 Daria Bignardi             2014         Mondadori
2      Memorie dal sottsuolo              Fëdor Dostoevskij             1864           Rizzoli
3                    Oblomov  Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov              1859       Feltrinelli
4  Le avventure di Pinocchio                  Carlo Collodi             1883            Giunti
```

Comment: Thank you so much. They are both very lovely methods. Except for the fact that the second method makes does not allow the addition of rows without changing the index. May you possibly know paths requiring the data.append() method?

Comment: `data.append` is deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: Hello, I was just wondering about the code to use in the case to add more than one row. I have published my second question here, if you pleas have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056401/how-to-enter-new-rows-in-a-dataset-by-keeping-same-index#comment129041803_73056401