# How to enter new rows in a dataset by keeping same index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataset, rows

I am trying to enter into the following dataset:

```
data = [("Il nome della rosa","Umberto Eco", 1980), 
        ("L'amore che ti meriti","Daria Bignardi", 2014), 
        ("Memorie dal sottsuolo", " Fëdor Dostoevskij", 1864), 
        ("Oblomov", "Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov ", 1859)]

index = range(1,5,1)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Books'Title", "Authors", "Publishing Year"], index = index)
data

pubhouses = ["Bompiani", "Mondadori", "Rizzoli", "Feltrinelli"]
data.insert(3, 'Publication House', pubhouses)
data
```

the rows:

```
newbook1 = ['Il demone meschino', 'Fëdor Sologub',  1907, 'Feltrinelli']
newbook2 = ['le anime morte', 'Nikolaj Vasilevič Gogol Janovskij',  1882, 'Garzanti']
```

As you could see, the dataset created with the first chunk of code turns a with the first row marked with index 1.

[image]

To maintain it, I used the following code to add two further rows ***where the new rows are added as follows at the last one of the original dataset***:

```
data.loc[len(data.index[-1] + 1)] = [newbook1, newbook2]
```

But the code does not work. If possible I would like to ask someone how to deal with this issue and try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Can you [edit] to show your current output and your expected output, so that we can understand better?

Comment: Ok. I will add some details.

Comment: Ok, maybe now I guess it will be clearer.

Comment: It is still not clear what you expect the index to _look like_ after you add the rows. Are you saying you want the new rows to be added at the end and the new index numbers to be 5 and 6? Or 0 and 1? Are you saying you want to add the rows at the top and the new index to start at 1 and push the existing rows to index 5 and 6? Including your expected output would really help us to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question and the expectation as well (in this case, it is the first one that you have mentioned)

Comment: The simplest solution might just be to set the index at the end, like `<all your concatenations>; data.index=range(1,len(data.index)+1)`

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit confused. What do you mean by putting the index at the end? Do you mind just showing how you would  organize the code down below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# create temporary dataframe with desired index
idx = data.index.max() + 1
x = pd.DataFrame(
    [newbook1, newbook2],
    index=range(idx, idx + 2),
    columns=data.columns,
)

# concat the dataframes
data = pd.concat([data, x])
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
             Books'Title                            Authors  Publishing Year Publication House
1     Il nome della rosa                        Umberto Eco             1980          Bompiani
2  L'amore che ti meriti                     Daria Bignardi             2014         Mondadori
3  Memorie dal sottsuolo                  Fëdor Dostoevskij             1864           Rizzoli
4                Oblomov      Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov              1859       Feltrinelli
5     Il demone meschino                      Fëdor Sologub             1907       Feltrinelli
6         le anime morte  Nikolaj Vasilevič Gogol Janovskij             1882          Garzanti
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but I think you could create a new dataframe, and the concat them (and ignore the index)

```
pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame([newbook1, newbook2], columns=data.columns)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, the code above works but it changes the index (the first row changes the index from 1 to 0) and I am interested to include new rows without changing the index. If something springs to your mind, please just let me know (maybe the key will be to modify this code `data.loc[len(data.index[-1] + 1)] = [newbook1, newbook2])`

Comment: What is your use case for fixing the DataFrame index like that? I think it might make more sense for you to add a new column with that number identifier if you want it to be closely tied to that data row

Comment: @falafeocelot maybe it is a method I have already used. But the crucial point that I am interested the most in is conserving the original index of the dataframe, starting with 1. Other methods but the one that  I have used (that actually works fine just when just ONE ROW has to be added up) do not work. So my aim is to find out some code that allows to add up more than one row without changing the index. Since I am a beginner, if you please show your idea, just feel free to share it.