# Append datetime to new row - python

Tags: python, pandas, append

I'm trying to append the current datetime to a new row for each script execution. By script execution, I mean each time the script is run. I also am adding a string value as a separate column.

I'm currently returning nan values as per output.

Also, each time I execute the script, new rows aren't appending to the existing df. It just updates to the most recent time. But I'm aiming to store each timestamp to record when the script was executed.

```
times = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'DateTime'])


def appendfunc():

    string = 'Cat'

    ct = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    rows = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': string}, {'DateTime': ct}])

    df = pd.concat([times, rows])

    return df 

df = appendfunc()
```

Let's assume the first executions is at `2022-01-24 10:00:00`.

Output:

```
         Name             DateTime
0         Cat                  NaN
1         NaN  2022-01-24 10:00:00
```

If the first run is at `2022-01-24 10:00:00` and the 2nd execution of the script is 5 mins later, the output should look like this.

intended output:

```
         Name             DateTime
0         Cat  2022-01-24 10:00:00
1         Cat  2022-01-24 10:05:00
```

Comment: What is your question? If you're asking for a review of your code, StackOverflow isn't really the right place (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited, although you'd need a bit more code ). If you're asking for suggestions, you should focus on a specific problem you're having trouble solving. (Note: it seems like you're confusing the log you could be writing to with your code in .py files - you probably want to write log lines to a file, or perhaps a simple database file like SQLite, so you can query it)

Comment: In the future post to codereview.stackechange.com for any code review.
Your question is very unclear, it would be helpful to include details about what went wrong eg. error messages. ---
Regardless, Im not sure what you have tried, but I imagine you would want to use pd.append to append new rows. Below are links to documentation and a stack exchange thread. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe Alternatively: how are checking whether or not the row was added?
may

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep the state of the dataframe between two invocations of the program? Then you need to write the data to a file and read it again from there.

Comment: Thanks. I've simplified the question

Comment: Stop reposting this question over and over. Again: __write the data to a file, read the data from the file.__ If you want to retain values between independent invocations of a program, you need to store that data somewhere. It's not going to stay "in the variable".

Comment: Fair but that link isn't remotely what the question is asking.

Comment: Well, you keep changing the question around… And how exactly isn't it an answer to the question?

Comment: Yeh I updated it after the first comment. I'm happy to delete it. But I'm trying to ask a NEW specific question that has nothing to do with the old one yet you keep flagging it. You you could remove the duplicate label, I'll delete it.

Comment: It'd be best if you could edit this question here to make sense. What exactly do you mean by "for each execution"? Does that mean _calling the function_, or _running (and stopping) the program_? Also what does "returning nan values" mean? Be sure to provide a [mre].

Comment: Ok. I've edited it. Execution means running the program

Comment: OK, so you _are_ trying to retain data between program runs. __Then the aforelinked duplicate in fact is very pertinent to your question.__ — The nan issue seems separate from that and should be tackled separately.

Comment: I'll just delete the question as the link will be just as helpful to other users..

Comment: *How* isn't it helpful? If you claim it's not, then tell us _why_. Have you tried implementing it and ran into some issue? Has your question been misunderstood after all?

Comment: The nan's are throwing me. I'll investigate elsewhere. I'll remove those from the question and align with links