# Insert Row in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, insert, row, dataframe

(I´m new to python, sorry for any mistakes I make, I hope you can understand me)

I have searched for a method to insert a Row into a Pandas DataFrame in Python, and I have found this:

[add one row in a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

I have use the code provided in the accepted answer of that topic by fred, but the code overwrites my row:
My code (Inserts a row with values "-1" for each column in certains conditions):

```
df.loc[i+1] = [-1 for n in range(len(df.columns))]
```

How can I make the code insert a row WITHOUT overriding it?
For example, if I have a 50 row DataFrame, insert a row in position 25 (Just as an example), and make the DataFrame have 51 rows (Being the 25 a extra NEW row).

I hope you can understand my question. (Sorry for any english mistakes)

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Someone suggested this:

[Is it possible to insert a row at an arbitrary position in a dataframe using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888648/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-at-an-arbitrary-position-in-a-dataframe-using-pan)

Tried, did not work. In fact, it does nothing, does not add any row.

```
 line = pd.DataFrame({[-1 for n in range(len(df.columns))]}, index=[i+1])
 df = pd.concat([ df.ix[:i],  line,  df.ix[i+1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert a row at an arbitrary position in a dataframe using pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888648/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-at-an-arbitrary-position-in-a-dataframe-using-pan)

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a small `DataFrame`, if you want to insert a line, at position `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1],'b':[2,3]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame([4,5]).T  

pd.concat([df[:1], df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(df1.columns,df.columns))), df[1:]])

#Out[46]: 
#   a  b
#0  0  2
#0  4  5
#1  1  3
```