# insert missing category for each group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I need to insert missing category for each group, here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ "group":[1,1,1 ,2,2],
                   "cat": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'] ,
                   "value": range(5),
                   "value2": np.array(range(5))* 2})

df

# test dataframe

cat group   value value2
a   1         0   0
b   1         1    2
c   1         2    4
a   2         3    6
c   2         4    8
```

say I  have some `categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. if `cat` column
does not contain a category from the list, I would like to insert
a row, for each group with value `0`.
how to insert a row per group if category, so as to get all the categories for each group

```
cat group   value  value2
a   1         0    0
b   1         1    2
c   1         2    4
d   1         0    0
a   2         3    6
c   2         4    8
b   2         0    0
d   2         0    0
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599589/inserting-new-rows-in-pandas-data-frame-at-specific-indices)

Comment: Please check timings in my answer, `groupby` here is really not necessary.

Comment: What about `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), df['group1'].unique(), categories], names=('group','group1','cat'))` and then `df.set_index(['group','group1','cat']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit complicated, but you can use `groupby` + `reindex`:

```
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def f(x):
    return x.reindex(categories, fill_value=0)\
                   .assign(group=x['group'][0].item())

df.set_index('cat').groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index()


  cat  group  value  value2
0   a      1      0       0
1   b      1      1       2
2   c      1      2       4
3   d      1      0       0
4   a      2      3       6
5   b      2      0       0
6   c      2      4       8
7   d      2      0       0
```

Answer (score 5):

`groupby` here is not neccesary, only need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex`:

```
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), categories], names=('group','cat'))
df = df.set_index(['group','cat']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).swaplevel(0,1).reset_index()
print (df)
  cat  group  value  value2
0   a      1      0       0
1   b      1      1       2
2   c      1      2       4
3   d      1      0       0
4   a      2      3       6
5   b      2      0       0
6   c      2      4       8
7   d      2      0       0
```

There is a lot of solutions, so I add **timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcd') #235,94.1,156ms

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': np.random.choice(L, N, p=(0.002,0.002,0.005, 0.991)),
                   'group':np.random.randint(10000,size=N),
                   'value':np.random.randint(1000,size=N),
                   'value2':np.random.randint(5000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['group','cat']).drop_duplicates(['group','cat']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df.head(10))

categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def jez(df):

    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), categories], names=('group','cat'))
    return df.set_index(['group','cat']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).swaplevel(0,1).reset_index()

def f(x):
    return x.reindex(categories, fill_value=0).assign(group=x['group'][0].item())

def coldspeed(df):
    return df.set_index('cat').groupby('group', group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index()
```

---

```
def zero(df):
    from itertools import product
    dfo = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['group'].unique(), categories)),
                            columns=['group', 'cat'])
    return dfo.merge(df, how='left').fillna(0)

def wen(df):
    return df.groupby('group',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('cat').reindex(categories)).fillna(0).reset_index().drop('level_0',1)

def bharath(df):
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), categories], names=('group','cat'))
    return mux.to_frame().merge(df,on=['cat','group'],how='outer').fillna(0)

def akilat90(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('group')
    categories =  pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['cat'])
    merged_list = []
    for g in grouped:
        merged = pd.merge(categories, g[1], how = 'outer', on='cat')
        merged['group'].fillna(merged['group'].mode()[0],inplace=True) # replace the `group` column's `NA`s by mode
        merged.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        merged_list.append(merged)

    return pd.concat(merged_list)


print (jez(df))
print (coldspeed(df))
print (zero(df))
print (wen(df))
print (bharath(df))
print (akilat90(df))
```

---

```
In [262]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop

In [263]: %timeit (bharath(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop

In [264]: %timeit (zero(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop

In [265]: %timeit (wen(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 8.74 s per loop

In [266]: %timeit (coldspeed(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 8.2 s per loop

In [297]: %timeit (akilat90(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 23.6 s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one line solution ...

```
df.groupby('group',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('cat').\
       reindex(categories)).fillna(0).reset_index().drop('level_0',1)
Out[601]: 
  cat  group  value  value2
0   a    1.0    0.0     0.0
1   b    1.0    1.0     2.0
2   c    1.0    2.0     4.0
3   d    0.0    0.0     0.0
4   a    2.0    3.0     6.0
5   b    0.0    0.0     0.0
6   c    2.0    4.0     8.0
7   d    0.0    0.0     0.0
```

Comment: In this solution, the `group` is filled with 0, while the group number is expected

Answer (score 2):

We can also use multi index as suggested by @jezreal then merge the data which significantly a very faster solution i.e

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), categories], names=('group','cat'))
ndf = mux.to_frame().merge(df,on=['cat','group'],how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Output :

```
 cat  group  value  value2
0   a      1    0.0     0.0
1   b      1    1.0     2.0
2   c      1    2.0     4.0
3   d      1    0.0     0.0
4   a      2    3.0     6.0
5   b      2    0.0     0.0
6   c      2    4.0     8.0
7   d      2    0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` on precomputed combinations of `cat, group`

```
In [35]: from itertools import product

In [36]: cats = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [37]: dfo = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['group'].unique(), cats)),
                            columns=['group', 'cat'])

In [38]: dfo.merge(df, how='left').fillna(0)
Out[38]:
   group cat  value  value2
0      1   a    0.0     0.0
1      1   b    1.0     2.0
2      1   c    2.0     4.0
3      1   d    0.0     0.0
4      2   a    3.0     6.0
5      2   b    0.0     0.0
6      2   c    4.0     8.0
7      2   d    0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant way to do this; I wish if I knew a way to merge at group level so that the for loop can be eliminated. [That discussion is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118695/merging-groups-with-a-one-dataframe-after-a-groupby)

---

**Solution**

Think of `categories` list as a dataframe and do merging at a group level after a group by.

```
categories =  pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['cat'])
print(categories)

grouped = df.groupby('group')
```

This is the ugly part. I wonder if there's a pandas way to eliminate this for loop:

```
merged_list = []
for g in grouped:
    merged = pd.merge(categories, g[1], how = 'outer', on='cat')
    merged['group'].fillna(merged['group'].mode()[0],inplace=True) # replace the `group` column's `NA`s by mode
    merged.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    merged_list.append(merged)
    print(merged)

  cat  group  value  value2
0   a    1.0    0.0     0.0
1   b    1.0    1.0     2.0
2   c    1.0    2.0     4.0
3   d    1.0    0.0     0.0
  cat  group  value  value2
0   a    2.0    3.0     6.0
1   b    2.0    0.0     0.0
2   c    2.0    4.0     8.0
3   d    2.0    0.0     0.0
```

Then we can just concat the `merged_list`

```
out = pd.concat(merged_list)
print(out)


  cat  group  value  value2
0   a    1.0    0.0     0.0
1   b    1.0    1.0     2.0
2   c    1.0    2.0     4.0
3   d    1.0    0.0     0.0
0   a    2.0    3.0     6.0
1   b    2.0    0.0     0.0
2   c    2.0    4.0     8.0
3   d    2.0    0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add your solution to my timings, because I get error :(

Comment: @akilat90 - I get it, I forget conver `categories` to `DataFrame`. Your solution was added to timings.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. The for loop + groupby merge is terrible :(

Comment: I am afraid it is True :(

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't clear. See my [answer to your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118758/4909087)  on how to spruce this code, you can do this in a single line.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the nice pythonic one liner! But, that was a little trimmed down version of this. Notice that I use an overcomplicated `mode` method to fill the `group` column here? That is not included in the other question. I wonder if it's still possible to write by a list comprehension.