# Append rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a dataframe below:

| Date_time | State | Time_in_state(Hour) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/8/2022 6:30:00 | State A | 1.3 |
| 10/8/2022 7:40:00 | State B | 0.3 |

I need to inject 2 row at 7:00:00 using Python `pd.append` function base on the condition below:

| Date_time | State | Time_in_state(Hour) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/8/2022 6:30:00 | State A | 1.3 |
| 10/8/2022 7:00:00 | State A | 0.5 |
| 10/8/2022 7:00:00 | State A | 0.667 |
| 10/8/2022 7:40:00 | State B | 0.3 |

Samilar to :

| Date_time | State | Time_in_state(Hour) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/8/2022 18:30:00 | State A | 1.3 |
| 10/8/2022 19:00:00 | State A | 0.5 |
| 10/8/2022 19:00:00 | State A | 0.667 |
| 10/8/2022 19:40:00 | State B | 0.3 |

Really need your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert a row at an arbitrary position in a dataframe using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888648/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-at-an-arbitrary-position-in-a-dataframe-using-pan)

Comment: Thank you for your cmt. There's not specific for the conditions of index.

Comment: `There's not specific for the conditions of index.` What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean in this case, I tried to look at the 'Date_time' column. Whenever the transition from 6:xx:xx to 7:xx:xx or 18:xx:xx to 19:xx:xx It's also insert two row 7:00:00.  'line = DataFrame({"onset": 30.0, "length": 1.3}, index=[3])' you can see this example, It's treat the index to 3 for inserting.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to insert the rows at a position such that the dataframe stays sorted with respect to that column? You can do that by appending to the end, then sorting it.