# pandas - creating new rows of combination with value of 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas dataframe like

| user_id | music_id | has_rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 1 |
| B | b | 1 |

and I would like to automatically add new rows for each of user_id & music_id for those users haven't rated, like

| user_id | music_id | has_rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 1 |
| A | b | 0 |
| B | a | 0 |
| B | b | 1 |

for each of user_id and music_id combination pairs those are not existing in my Pandas dataframe yet.

is there any way to append such rows automatically like this?

Comment: To make sure I understand the question, you'd want to go and find all combinations of `user_id` and `music_id`, and for those that don't exist, add a new line with `has_rating` = 0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888648/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-at-an-arbitrary-position-in-a-dataframe-using-pan

Comment: Hi Zach, yes - if the combination pair of user_id and music_id already exists, no need to add, but if it doesn't exist, I would like to add a new line with has_rating = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary reshape with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and `fill_value=0` to fill the missing values with `0`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='music_id',
                values='has_rating', fill_value=0)
   .stack().reset_index(name='has_rating')
 )
```

Output:

```
  user_id music_id  has_rating
0       A        a           1
1       A        b           0
2       B        a           0
3       B        b           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`

```
l = ['user_id','music_id']

(df.set_index(l)
.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[l[0]].unique(),df[l[1]].unique()],names = l),fill_value=0)
.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  user_id music_id  has_rating
0       A        a           1
1       A        b           0
2       B        a           0
3       B        b           1
```